# Break line tooltip angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, tooltip

i'd like to know if someone knows how to jump a line in the angular material component "tooltip"

Here my code :

**HTML :**

```
<mat-icon 
   [matTooltip]="getMoreInformations()"
   matTooltipPosition="left">
   myIcon
</mat-icon>
```

**TS :**

```
getMoreInformations(): string {
   return 'Adress : ' + this.person.adress
      + ' \n  Tel : ' +  this.person.tel;
   }
```

\n and br doesn't work (tried both)

Also tried to add a matTooltipClass like this:

**HTML :**

```
<mat-icon...
  matTooltipClass="test"
...
```

**CSS :**

```
.test {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)? The `white-space: pre` solution is working for me

Comment: idk why i dont get the tooltip on stackblitz, here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apnthv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's an example using your markup/code (which works fine) - [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrrwqb)

To get the CSS to work I had to put the class in the file *styles.css* rather than the component stylesheet. This was taken from **willshowell**'s comment to this issue - https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8316

Edit: The following works in the component stylesheet

```
::ng-deep .test {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

The [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) suggests `::ng-deep` is deprecated but it still works with the latest version.

Comment: Had the same issue, but including `::ng-deep` in fact made it not work. Just declaring the class in my `styles.css` worked, using Angular 7.

Comment: thank you for correcting angular material tooltip :-)

Comment: using Angluar 8 this does not work. I have tried with ::ng-deep and without. I have tried including the css in both style and component and using the `!important` flag.

Comment: Working for me in Angular 8 with `::ng-deep`

Comment: Also, I converted the `getMoreInformations()` method to a custom pipe because calling methods from the template file is terrible for performance.

Answer (score 0):

```
::ng-deep <tootltipCLassName>{
white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Still working with angular 10